# mysql update time between innodb and myisam

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, myisam

I did a test on a table (with innodb and myisam), which use PHP to simulate 2 set of update, as follow

set 1. // execute 1000 times
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
   { update with pdo }

set 2. // execute 1 time
   { update with pdo }

normally, each update take ~0.001x sec with myisam and ~0.03x sec with innodb, so not surprise for set 1 use 1000 more times then set 2, however, during testing set 1, I open set 2 at another browser windows, what I expect is the result will return within the total time of set 1, but it seems it wait for set 1 finish, rather then insert into the queue during set 1 running.

Am I did something wrong or my concept is wrong?
And is the update time slow?(my pc config is AMD Athlon 64 4200+, 2G RAM, Windows 7, MySQL 5.5.9, nginx 0.8.5, PHP 5.3.5)

thanks a lot~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MyISAM tables, concurrent inserts are an issue.  See

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/concurrent-inserts.html

If you are inserting to an InnoDB table with an auto_increment column, there's a discussion of locking issues here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html